# Windows command working in cmd but not in .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Hello i am trying create windows script for extract subtitles from all .mkv files in directory and i run to problem.

This is my script:

```
dir /b | findstr .*".mkv"$ > tmpFile
for /f "tokens=*" %f in (tmpFile) do start mkvextract.exe tracks %f 2:%~nf.ass
del tmpFile
```

Problem is that when i am executing it in cmd.exe everything works OK, but when i wrap it in .bat file only first and third line can be executed.

for line saying this error

```
C:\test>dir /b   | findstr .*".mkv"$  1>tmpFile
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~nf.ass

For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /?
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\test>for /f "tokens=*" f 2:n (tmpFile) do start
mkvextract.exe tracks %f 2:%~nf.ass
```

I was trying alter script to fix error but only thing i achieved was that is stopped working even in command line. Please help. :)

Comment: what is the idea behind `findstr .*".mkv"$`  ?

Comment: @npocmaka: The first `.*` is the regexp for "any char zero or more times", the `".mkv"` part is the literal ".mkv", and the `$` at end is the regexp for "at end of line"!

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that you must double the percent signs when the commands are placed in a Batch file, as npocmaka indicated in his answer. However, I would like to analyze your code a little. In this line:

```
dir /b | findstr .*".mkv"$ > tmpFile
```

The `dir /b` command generate a list of file names, the `findstr` command get just the names that start with any string and ends in ".mkv", and the redirection store such names in "tmpFile". The net effect of previous line is "store the file names with .mkv extension in tmpFile". (You may get the same result with `dir /b *.mkv > tmpFile` command).

The second line:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %f in (tmpFile) do start mkvextract.exe tracks %f 2:%~nf.ass
```

process previous names and for each one execute a `start ...` command. The net effect is "execute the `start ...` command on each file with .mkv extension". The last line:

```
del tmpFile
```

just delete the auxiliary file.

You may get the same result of three previous lines with this command:

```
for %f in (*.mkv) do start mkvextract.exe tracks %f 2:%~nf.ass
```

If you want to place previous command in a Batch file, just double the percent signs:

```
for %%f in (*.mkv) do start mkvextract.exe tracks %%f 2:%%~nf.ass
```

Comment: Thank you last row doing exacly what i wanted it

Answer (score 1):

WHat `dir /b | findstr .*".mkv"$ > tmpFile` should do (looks like javascript regex)?

in batch file you need double `%` for the FOR tokens:

```
dir /b | findstr  /i /e ".mkv" > tmpFile
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (tmpFile) do start mkvextract.exe tracks %%f 2:%%~nf.ass
del tmpFile
```

though it can be done without temp file:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b ^| findstr  /i /e ".mkv"') do start mkvextract.exe tracks %%f 2:%%~nf.ass
```

Comment: Thank you i was trying do only pipeline without ^ in brackled but it didnt work so i used tempfile to get it working